# add an image to an alert from a json file when an id is entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have an alert box that appears for a user when they enter their id. In the alert box the name appears, however I would also like to get an image to appear as wel as their name and the welcome message.

This is my json:

```
{
"user":[
{
"ID" : "001",
"Imgpath":"image/iphone5.jpg",
"name": "Zara Ali"

},
{
"ID" : "002",
"Imgpath":"image/iphone5.jpg",
"name": "Laura Ali"
},
{
"ID" : "003",
"Imgpath":"image/iphone5.jpg",
"name": "Courtney Ali"
 },
 {
"ID" : "004",
"Imgpath":"image/iphone5.jpg",
"name": "Max Ali"
}
]
}
```

This is my script pulling the name to the alert box:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Hide alert when page loads
$("#loginalert").hide();    
$("#loginbtn").click(function(event){
//console.log("clicked login");
$.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
  var id = $('#userName').val();
  //console.log(id);
  for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) {
    if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {
      $('#loginalert').html('<p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>');      
      //show the alert after loading the information
        $("#loginalert").stop().fadeIn('slow').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 3000)('slow', function () {
        $('#contact').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    } }});}); });
```

and this is the text box/button that needs clicked when entering te user id:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
<input type="text" id="userName" value> <button type="button"  id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Login</button></div>
```

I was trying to include the image doing this, however it did not work:

```
if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {
  $('#loginalert').html('<p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + jd.user[i].imgpath +'</p>');      
  //show the alert after loading the information
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you almost got it.

Just instead of outputting `imgpath` as text, put it in an `img` tag, like so:

```
$('#loginalert').html('<img src="' + jd.user[i].imgpath + '"><br><p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>');
```